# Share intent imageview

Tags: android

Bom galera estou querendo fazer um **Share / Compartilhamento** de uma imagem com `intent`, porém esta imagem já esta definida com um `id`.

Como faço para realizar este *share*?
Segue o meu código que está dando erro:

```
// Metodo do botão
public void Share (View view){

//Ter Acesso a imaem atraves do 
ImageView ivCar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_car);

    Intent sharingIntent =  new  Intent ( Intent .ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images. Media . EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI +  "/"  + ivCar );
    sharingIntent . setType("image/jpeg");
sharingIntent . putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser ( sharingIntent ,  "Share imagem usando " ));
```

Comment: A imagem que está na *ImageView* vem de onde?

Comment: Verifique no logcat o endereço da imagem, talvez seja necessário converter o endereço. para facilitar mostre-nos o logcat do erro.